# Erratic management of dual-display configuration on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, intel-graphics, login-screen, wayland

I have two displays connected to my PC with Intel UHD Graphics 630 running Ubuntu 20.04.3. 40" display #2 on HDMI1 port is disabled in configuration, 20" display #1 on DVI-D is my main display. Here is the screen capture:

[image]

Here are the problems:

1. The login dialog is displayed on the disabled display #2
2. As you can see on the picture, orientation of display #1 is incorrectly shown as `Landscape`. On the third launch of `Settings -> Displays` it changes to the correct `Portrait Right`

I only care about login dialog displayed outside of primary screen. I think this problem started after I switched to Wayland, in order to avoid screen tearing. Here are my graphics details:

```
paul@desktop:~$ inxi -Gxx
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:3e98 
           Display: wayland server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: i915 compositor: gnome-shell resolution: 1200x1600~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.3 direct render: Yes
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

---

Upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and the problem remains...

Comment: You could set the secondary to the same screen real estate as the primary before disabling. Set to MODE+0+0 with `xrandr` and then disable. reverse when enabling. X Server is whacky in 20.4.3.

Comment: @NateT Thanks, but that's a bit too much hassle. Blind login is easier.